# Converting Floats to String in Mixed Type DF Column Uses Scientific Notation

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-notation, mixed-type

I have a dataframe with a column that is being read in with mixed types.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mix':['a',6,0.23423,False, 0.000023425]})
```

I want to convert the column to strings, but when I do so, any long decimals get converted to scientific notation. How do I keep all decimals in decimal notation?

```
df.astype(str)
    mix
0   a
1   6
2   0.23423
3   False
4   2.3425e-11
```

**Desired output:**

```
    mix
0   a
1   6
2   0.23423
3   False
4   0.000000000023425
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the numpy [format_float_positional](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html) function, as follows.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'mix':['a',6,0.23423,False, 0.000000000023425]})

def custom_str(x):
    if isinstance(x, float):
        return np.format_float_positional(x)
    return str(x)

df['mix'].apply(custom_str)
```

Output:

```
0                    a
1                    6
2              0.23423
3                False
4    0.000000000023425
```

Comment: if `x` is already an instance of `float`, why do you make it `float(x)` again? Also, why the `try/catch` block? Any chances `np.format_float_positional` raises an error?

Comment: Good spot! They were the leftovers from a failed original approach. I've updated the answer.